# Why Reflector ver 7 produced wrong Linq code like this

Tags: c#, linq, reflector

```
private FileStorageFolder GetCapsuleContentFolder(FileStorageDataContext db)
{
    IQueryable<FileStorageFolder> source = from dbFolder in db.FileStorageFolders
        where (dbFolder.ParentID == null) && (dbFolder.Purpose == reportFolderPurpose)
        select dbFolder into dbFolder
        join dbSubFolder in db.FileStorageFolders on dbFolder.ID equals 
        dbSubFolder.ParentID into dbSubFolder
         where (dbSubFolder.Purpose == capsulelayoutFolderPurpose) && 
        (dbSubFolder.FolderName == capsuleReportContent)
         select dbSubFolder;

Instrument.Assert(source.Count<FileStorageFolder>() == 1);
return source.Single<FileStorageFolder>();
}
```

this is not correct syntax.Does anyone know how to create IQueryable typed base on this?

Comment: Send a bug report to JetBrains?

Comment: @rickythefox pretty sure that JetBrains will say "why are you telling us? tell Red Gate!"

Comment: @sofyan_visi it would help if you made it explicit which part is not correct... that's a lot of linq to took at...

Comment: @rickythefox off course...thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is problematic, try cranking down the "Optimisation" setting to, say, .NET 2.0. This will then be forced to display the explicit `.Select(...)` etc. This should produce correct C#, but without the LINQ style.

Note, however, that it may also reverse the apparent call-order, since it will probably use explicit extension-method representation. The code should be equivalent either way, though.

Comment: how should I handle a lot of  "AnonymousType0<" when optimisation set to .NET 2.0

Comment: @sofyan well,  what is the context? If you were meant to be doing this you would already have the code...

Comment: sorry...I just a little confused to resolve the problem.anyway thanks a lot for your response